# Which one is correct, semester or semesters?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

This information is for 4th and 5th **semester?**

or

This information is for 4th and 5th **semesters?**

Comment: There are two semesters. (Also, **the** should come before *4th*.)

Answer (score 2):

As Jason said, it should read 'the 4th and 5th'... and the answer is 'semesters', because there are two of them. Some English users might say 'semester' because the immediate antecedent is '5th', but that is a casual mistake.